# Trying to create a Client for a JAX WS Provider using JAXWSProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, web-services, client, jax-ws

Ok, so I came across an example on how to create a client using JaxWsProxyFactoryBean for an SEI-

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
factory.setServiceClass(HelloWorld.class);
factory.setAddress("http://localhost:9000/helloWorld");
HelloWorld client = (HelloWorld) factory.create();
String reply = client.sayHi("HI");
System.out.println("Server said: " + reply);
System.exit(0); `
```

I tried to duplicate it for a JAX WS Provider Interface(since I couldn't find any examples)-

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    System.out.println("TEST");
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    System.out.println("TEST");
    factory.setAddress("http://localhost:8123/SoapContext/SoapPort1");
    System.out.println("TEST");
    factory.setServiceClass(Provider.class);
    System.out.println("TEST");
    factory.setWsdlLocation("http://localhost:8123/SoapContext/SoapPort1?wsdl");
    System.out.println("TEST");
    Provider<SOAPMessage> client = (Provider<SOAPMessage>) factory.create();
    //Below Never Prints
    System.out.println("TEST");

    SOAPFactory sf = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage request = mf.createMessage();
    SOAPBody reqBody = request.getSOAPBody();
    Name bodyName = sf.createName("ClientInsertedmainbody");
    reqBody.addBodyElement(bodyName);
    SOAPElement reqContent = reqBody.addChildElement("client");
    reqContent.setValue("JPFB\n");
    SOAPElement reqContent2 = reqBody.addChildElement("client2");
    reqContent2.setValue("clieennnt\n");

    System.out.println(" Request from client " + request.getSOAPBody().getTextContent());


    System.out.println("Invoking server through JPFB interface using SOAPMessage");

    SOAPMessage soapResp = client.invoke(request);
    System.out.println("Response from server: " + soapResp.getSOAPBody().getTextContent());

    System.exit(0);
}
```

Anyway, it fails. The server is working fine. It responded when I used a client created in another way (Using a Dispatch instance).

The error messages -

```
May 19, 2015 6:44:55 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL  
INFO: Creating Service {http://ws.xml.javax/}ProviderService from WSDL: http://localhost:8123/SoapContext/SoapPort1?wsdl  
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not find definition for service {http://ws.xml.javax/}ProviderService.  
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.create(WSDLServiceFactory.java:158)  
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:405)  
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:525)  
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:261)  
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:199)  
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)  
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:91)  
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:157)  
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)  
at main.JSFBClient.main(JSFBClient.java:40)
```

Right the question:  What's wrong and how do I fix it? I get the nagging feeling that the code I wrote might be completely off, but hey in that case, how would I do it?

EDIT : Here is the wsdl

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://localhost:8123/SoapContext/SoapPort1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:ns1="http://server/" name="Provider1" targetNamespace="http://localhost:8123/SoapContext/SoapPort1">
  <wsdl:import location="http://localhost:8123/SoapContext/SoapPort1?wsdl=Provider1.wsdl" namespace="http://server/">
    </wsdl:import>
  <wsdl:binding name="Provider1SoapBinding" type="ns1:Provider1">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="invoke">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="invoke">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="invokeResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="Provider1">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:Provider1SoapBinding" name="Provider1Port">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8123/SoapContext/SoapPort1"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Is the URL accessible? Show WSDL.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Check my edit. And thanks for editing my code :P... the formatting is a nightmare

Comment: I wonder where CXF got "{http://ws.xml.javax/}ProviderService". Take a look at http://localhost:8123/SoapContext/SoapPort1?wsdl=Provider1.wsdl. I would give a try to SoapUI - can it generate and run some tests for http://localhost:8123/SoapContext/SoapPort1?wsdl?

Comment: SoapUI? I'm afraid I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Give it a try. It is easy to use, intuitive. And I believe it can lead to solution

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove this line of code:

```
factory.setWsdlLocation("http://localhost:8123/SoapContext/SoapPort1");
```